# Unable to resolve NullPointerException in java swing application

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I made a simple login page with Java *Swing* in Eclipse and once I run and enter the inputs I am getting an error `java.lang.NullPointerException`

[image]

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class trail extends JFrame {
    Connection connection =null;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField id;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jdbcURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
        String username = "postgres";
        String password = ".......";
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, password);
            System.out.print("Connected");
            connection.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    trail frame = new trail();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public trail() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 519, 550);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("username");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(94, 114, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        id = new JTextField();
        id.setBounds(246, 111, 96, 19);
        contentPane.add(id);
        id.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("password");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(94, 178, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setBounds(246, 175, 96, 19);
        contentPane.add(passwordField);

        JButton btnlogin = new JButton("login");
        btnlogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String query = "select * from users where username = ? and password = ?";
                    PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    pst.setString(1, id.getText());
                    pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());
                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    int count = 0;
                    while(rs.next()) {
                        count = count + 1;
                        if(count == 1)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password and username is correct");
                        }
                        else if(count>1)
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "redundancy detected");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect credentials");
                        }
                    }
                    rs.close();
                    pst.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
                }
            }
        });
        btnlogin.setBounds(179, 259, 85, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnlogin);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code under the image which caused the exception. Edit your post and copy paste the code into it. You need to establish a connection to the database before playing out a query.

Comment: database connection was established successfully!!! @DevilsHnd

Comment: Why do you close that connection as soon as you open it!!!!

Comment: i changed it know...still the same nullpointe exception error @DevilsHnd

Comment: well the error is caught by the catch(e1)..which is at the bottom...so maybe something went wrong inside the try block below the actionlistener of btnlogin bottom @DevilsHnd

Comment: `Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(…` ← You are declaring a *brand new variable* named `connection`, and you are assigning a value to that.  This means the `connection` field declared at the top of your class is never assigned a value at all.

Comment: When using Eclipse [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) to build your _Swing_ GUI, you don't have to use null layout. Consider using [GroupLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) or [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) Also consider [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in your [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) code.

Comment: Also consider adhering to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `Connection connection =null;` later on in the try block you are using like

`Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, password)`  which is altogether different `Connection`  object. you should be using something like .

```
 this.connection=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, password)
```

Also you can move your code in a different method like

```
 public void  initialize() {
      String jdbcURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/your_db";
      String username = "postgres";
      String password = "password";

  try {
  this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, password);
  System.out.print("Connected");
  connection.close();      
  }
  catch(SQLException e) {
      System.out.println("Error in connection");
      e.printStackTrace();
  } 
}
```

And call inside the constructor like

```
 public trail() {
    initialize();
    ....
 }
```